# npm run rollup showing error message "Module ag-grid-ng2/main.js does not export AgGridModule".?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ag-grid, rollup

I'm trying to create the min.js file for my angular2 project using Tree shaking. So, earlier I were not using ag-grid for this so there was no error that time but now when I run **npm run rollup**  its throwing this error at console. I'm not sure whether it is my fault or library fault.
When I opened the main.js file of ag-grid it is exporting the AgGridModule and Now, I'm stuck.

**Below is the error message:**

```
Module /home/knoldus/yourManager/node_modules/ag-grid-ng2/main.js does not export AgGridModule (imported by /home/knoldus/yourManager/dist/temp/client/app/assets/asset.module.js)
    Error: Module /home/knoldus/yourManager/node_modules/ag-grid-ng2/main.js does not export AgGridModule (imported by /home/knoldus/yourManager/dist/temp/client/app/assets/asset.module.js)
        at Module.trace (/home/knoldus/yourManager/node_modules/rollup/src/Module.js:683:30)
        at /home/knoldus/yourManager/node_modules/rollup/src/Module.js:265:30
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at /home/knoldus/yourManager/node_modules/rollup/src/Module.js:263:25
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Module.bindReferences (/home/knoldus/yourManager/node_modules/rollup/src/Module.js:256:19)
        at /home/knoldus/yourManager/node_modules/rollup/src/Bundle.js:104:44
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at /home/knoldus/yourManager/node_modules/rollup/src/Bundle.js:104:18
    Type rollup --help for help, or visit https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki

    npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-36-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/knoldus/npm/bin/npm" "run" "rollup"
    npm ERR! node v6.2.2
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! yourmanager@1.0.0 rollup: `rollup -f iife -c -o dist/prod/client/app/bundle.es2015.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the yourmanager@1.0.0 rollup script 'rollup -f iife -c -o dist/prod/client/app/bundle.es2015.js'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the yourmanager package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     rollup -f iife -c -o dist/prod/client/app/bundle.es2015.js
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs yourmanager
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls yourmanager
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/knoldus/yourManager/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export default {
  entry: 'src/main.aot.js',
  dest: 'aot/dist/build.js', // output a single application bundle
  sourceMap: false,
  sourceMapFile: 'aot/dist/build.js.map',
  format: 'iife',
  plugins: [
      nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
      commonjs({
        include: ['node_modules/rxjs/**','node_modules/ng2-dragula/**',
        'node_modules/ng2-uploader/**','node_modules/dragula/**',
        'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2/**']`//look this`
      }),
      uglify()
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide descriptive comment to your answer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! @Maxim: adding the include for 'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2/**' is the fix for this issue.